# Persisting Fullscreen Split View Bar

Tags: finder, catalina, fullscreen, split-view

This often happens when I quit apps in fullscren split view mode? Has anyone encountered this too? Any known fix for this?

[image]

Comment: If it started happening without any new app installation, and only after a update, better file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/welcome

Comment: Yes. I've had this happen in 10.15.7. I'm surprised that no one has answered. Perhaps a rare bug indeed.